# Front end request got data but back end didn't send anything

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, session-cookies, mean-stack

It's too weird that the back end sent nothing but front end got data.

When I try to login and logout an account, the session in the back end will be cleared, but even if after removing the session, the front end still can receive session data.

in my router:

```
router.get('/session',              getSession);

var getSession = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.session);
    if(!req.user || req.user === undefined || !req.session || req.session === undefined) res.status(304).send({username: null, id: null, type: null, expires: null});
    else res.status(200).send({username: req.session.username, id: req.session.passport.user, type: req.session.type, sidebar: req.session.sidebar, expires: req.session.cookie._expires});
}
```

in my service factory:

```
function ValidateSession(cb) {
    $http.get('/session')
    .success(function (res) {
        console.log(res);
        cb('OK');
    })
    .error(function(response){
        if(!response.username || !response.id || !response.expires) {
            ClearCredentials();
            cb('NOSESSION');
        }
        else{
            var now = new Date();
            var expires = new Date(response.expires);
            var expired = now.getTime() > expires.getTime() ? true : false;
            if(expired) {
                ClearCredentials();
                cb('EXPIRED');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Then I refresh my login page,
the console log in the back end:

```
Session {
  cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: Wed Oct 05 2016 12:30:27 GMT+1100 (AUS Eastern Daylight Time),
     originalMaxAge: 7200000,
     httpOnly: true } }
```

the console.log in the service:

```
services.js:106 Object {username: "administrator", id: "57c6450bba7f948018b300ce", type: "admin", sidebar: false, expires: "2016-10-05T01:06:56.496Z"}
```

Comment: This code does not demonstrate that the server sent nothing. It just demonstrates that the "if" condition on the server passes. Your "console.log" statement only logs the session object, but the "if" condition checks req.user AND req.session, so if req.user is in fact present (which I assume it is) it would go into the else clause, and return all the data in that clause.

Comment: `req.user` is undefined, I've tested the router, it went to the first statement condition. But when it came to front end, the result changed.

Comment: When you try to console.log(req.user) prior to the if statement what does it say? The session will never be undefined (unless there's a problem with your middleware) and req.user isn't part of the req prototype so you must have something in there.

Comment: I tried both within and before the if statement, I'm sure that the server sent back response with the null object. The server console had the output of status code which was 304. `req.user` was generated by passport authentication. When an account logs out, it will be cleared.